# Collapse list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i'm very noob with jquery. I'm trying collapse a list. Everything is good if i use only inside ul but with this i can't find the error. I need show and hide (collapse) ul, clicking on parent td.

I have this HTML

```
<td class="parent">Button</td>
<td>
  <ul class="child">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

jQuery

```
     $('.child').hide();
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.parent').find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `children()` selector with your true parent element and `slideToggle()` OR use `$(this)` with `next().children()` and `slideToggle()` to lightly animate the toggle display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#row").on("click", "td", function() {
    $(this).next().children().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr id="row">
    <td class="parent">Button</td>
    <td>
      <ul class="child">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! Only one question. I don't need a button like that, i need use <td class="parent">Text</td> (complete td). Is possible with my html? thanks again

Comment: Okay, looks like jquery does not like clicking directly on a tr tag with the element called as its class... So, if you use the `.on( event, selector` method on its parents ID, it works.